# Tripling in Python produces list rather than string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write some code to triple each letter of a word. So hello becomes hhheeellllllooo etc. I can do it (via another method).

My problem is... why doesn't *the following code* work? It seems to output a list instead of a string - when I test the function - and I can't figure out why. I thought join could turn the list to a string?

```py
def triple(text):
    x=list(text)
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x[i]=x[i]+x[i]+x[i]
    ''.join(x)
    return x
```

Comment: in python you can multiply a string by an int, so for the tripling you can use `x[i] *= 3` instead of `x[i]=x[i]+x[i]+x[i]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`''.join(x)` does not update x. x is a list. You return x. You return a list.

```
def triple(text):
    x=list(text)
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x[i]=x[i]+x[i]+x[i]
    return ''.join(x)
```

or

```
def triple(text):
    x=list(text)
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x[i]=x[i]+x[i]+x[i]
    x = ''.join(x)
    return x
```

May I suggest two alternative answers:

-> Remove `range(len())` which looks always odd to me when iterating over a list:

```
def triple(text):
    x=list(text)
    for i, c in enumerate(x):
        x[i] = c*3
    return ''.join(x)
```

-> Use comprehension :

```
def triple(text):
    return ''.join(c*3 for c in text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you converted the list to string but didnot  save it to any variable and you are returning the list iteslf

```
def triple(text):
    x = list(text)
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] + x[i] + x[i]
    x =''.join(x)
    return x
```

or

```
def triple(text):
    x=list(text)
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x[i]=x[i]+x[i]+x[i]
    x = ''.join(x)
    return x
```

Comment: your code is not correctly indented, so will not run

Comment: Thanks @Adam.Er8. Just updated. Would you please change your vote.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I was so excited to answer. Messed up.lol

Answer (score 0):

```
def tripleGenerate(myStr):
    triplestr = ""
    for i in range(0,len(myStr)):
        triplestr += (myStr[i]*3)

    return triplestr
```

1. myStr is basically your string for example: ("hello")
2. After this I have initialize a new string tripleStr for storing the triples
3. Inside the loop I am first producing the triples by doing (myStr[i] * 3) and then concatenating these triples into my triplestr variable.